# Thrift HTTP transport error with PHP string

Tags: php, json, string, thrift

We're using thrift with PHP client. We try to sent string data and use json_encode to encapsulate the array object.

Here's the error when we try to send request. The string data looks fine but it throws `Unexpected character:\`.

```
"[{\"home_ssid\":\"\\\"TP-LINK_F196EE\\\"\",\"initial_time\":1420794654263,\"location_name\":\"home\",\"wifi_list\":[\"20:dc:e6:f1:96:ee\",\"38:83:45:c5:67:d0\",\"00:27:19:6b:75:f0\",\"c0:61:18:b5:e7:d2\",\"d0:c7:c0:ea:95:e0\",\"1c:fa:68:f5:ff:fa\",\"14:75:90:30:2b:ba\",\"d8:15:0d:19:f7:04\",\"02:34:cb:c0:3d:79\",\"14:14:4b:fd:3d:61\",\"00:34:cb:c0:3d:79\"]},{\"home_ssid\":\"deli--\\/\\/2014\",\"initial_time\":1420794654265,\"location_name\":\"office\",\"wifi_list\":[\"70:b9:21:3f:19:76\",\"6a:b9:21:3f:19:75\",\"04:c1:b9:24:0f:b4\",\"1c:fa:68:74:08:06\",\"e4:d3:32:55:d4:7e\",\"8c:be:be:08:19:20\"]}]" 

HTTP transport error [http status code: 400, error code: UNKNOWN, error message: Parse error: Unexpected character:\]
```

We have tried not using json_encode but the error occurs with another unexpected character.

Comment: I'm confused... Encoding the string (which is an encoded JSON) works [just fine](http://ideone.com/W2wV6g)...?

Comment: Yes, it's fine. But we have problems when we try to send thrift requests with this encoding string. Like what you see above it says "Unexpected character:\".

Comment: Oh, not familiar with thrift. Sorry. `:\\`

Comment: That's fine and thanks for your help @Shahar :-)

Comment: [possibly related: THRIFT-2345](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/THRIFT-2345)

Comment: Please post the code for your client, and also the server if possible.  Also please specify which transport you are using (binary, json) and the language of the server.  FYI I've had similar error messages occur in PHP when application errors occur on the server side

Comment: @BCG We're using the service that wraps thrift service which uses json and Java server. Now we add JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES when calling json_encode and it works for us.